ı can not import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
I created a deep learning model (with Inception), then converted this model to a tensorflow lite model to use in Flutter. Afterward, I added this model to the assets folder in Flutter.
But I cannot access the contents of the tflite_flutter package. So ı can not import package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
This is my main.dart file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kamera/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart'; 

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await loadModel();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Mobil Uygulama',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> loadModel() async {
  await TfliteFlutter.loadModel(
    model: 'assets/inceptionv3_model.tflite',
    // labels: 'assets/inceptionv3_labels.txt', 
  );
}

This is my pubspec.yml file:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: ^1.1.1
  tflite_flutter: ^0.10.4
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/inceptionv3_model.tflite

This is the error:
[{
    "resource": ".../AndroidStudioProjects/kamera/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "undefined_identifier",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/undefined_identifier",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined name 'TfliteFlutter'.\nTry correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 26,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 26,
    "endColumn": 22
}]


There are two seperate main packages for tensorflow in flutter.

tflite_flutter
flutter_tflite

I can see that you have imported the first one but you used the second package's model loading pattern.
You need to use following line to load the model with imported package;
final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/your_model.tflite');

Then you can use the interpreter to inference your model.
